# Jenkins job with subversion polling + optional revision

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a fetch job that monitors SVN for commits with 1 minute polling and then triggers N other jobs that inherit his workspace (using the clone workspace plugin)

Since it takes 30 minutes from the beginning of the SVN checkout to the moment when all the child jobs complete, it happens that at the end of the day the revisions checked out group more commits and we would like in a quiet moment to start the fetch job on a specific intermediate revision

I found that the SVN URL supports the @$REQUESTED_REVISION that can be passed as parameter in a parameterised job but unfortunately this seems to require a separate job. Having both the polling and this option causes the job to get disabled automatically (I assume for wrong configuration)

I wonder if there is a trick to have in the same job both the polling and the possibility to start on a specific revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

1) Parameterized job with **String Parameter** having **Name** = **SVN_PEG_PARAMETER** and **Default Value** = **HEAD**

2) Repository URL with trailing **@${SVN_PEG_PARAMETER}**

3) **Poll SCM** enabled with the desired frequency

This works with the polling pointing to the default revision (which is **HEAD**) and the possibility to input a specific revision.

There is a problem though, after running a build with a pegged revision, the next polling will trigger again a fetch to the HEAD

**UPDATE for versions <= 2.6**:

Unfortunately I had a situation where the svn checkout job kept being disabled at every polling if **@${SVN_PEG_PARAMETER}** was at the end of the URL.

To fix this issue I made a modification to the original subversion plugin visible in https://github.com/giuspen/subversion-plugin/tree/atmel where the point **2)** is not necessary anymore (branch name "atmel-2.6.0", tag name "2.6.0-Atmel")

To build it and produce **target/subversion.hpi**:

```
git clone https://github.com/giuspen/subversion-plugin.git
cd subversion-plugin
git checkout atmel-2.6.0
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```